# JBoss 5.1 failed to start (just hung with no error messages) on AIX

Tags: jboss, jboss5.x

Here is the message and got hung after started the scheduler.  No error messages.  Any suggestion to trace out the problem?  It was working fine yesterday, just re-starting this morning.  No changes to the deployed applications.  But we had about a million jms messages, deleted all from JBoss admin console.

```
12:30:40,233 INFO  [ProfileServiceBootstrap] Loading profile: ProfileKey@11c611c6[domain=default, server=default, name=default]
[2012-11-28 12:33:51,325] [main] [WARN ] org.jboss.jms.server.jbosssx.JBossASSecurityMetadataStore: WARNING! POTENTIAL SECURITY RISK. It has been detected that the MessageSucker component which sucks messages from one node to another has not had its password changed from the installation default. Please see the JBoss Messaging user guide for instructions on how to do this.
[2012-11-28 12:33:51,606] [main] [WARN ] org.jboss.annotation.factory.AnnotationCreator: No ClassLoader provided, using TCCL: org.jboss.managed.api.annotation.ManagementComponent
[2012-11-28 12:33:51,964] [main] [WARN ] org.jboss.annotation.factory.AnnotationCreator: No ClassLoader provided, using TCCL: org.jboss.managed.api.annotation.ManagementComponent
[2012-11-28 12:33:52,153] [main] [INFO ] com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService: JBossTS Transaction Service (JTA version - tag:JBOSSTS_4_6_1_GA) - JBoss Inc.
[2012-11-28 12:33:52,153] [main] [INFO ] com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService: Setting up property manager MBean and JMX layer
[2012-11-28 12:33:52,606] [main] [INFO ] com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService: Initializing recovery manager
[2012-11-28 12:33:52,933] [main] [INFO ] com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService: Recovery manager configured
[2012-11-28 12:33:52,933] [main] [INFO ] com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService: Binding TransactionManager JNDI Reference
[2012-11-28 12:33:53,006] [main] [INFO ] com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.jta.TransactionManagerService: Starting transaction recovery manager
[2012-11-28 12:33:54,434] [main] [INFO ] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener: The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: {my path displayed here}
[2012-11-28 12:33:55,335] [main] [INFO ] org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol: Initializing Coyote HTTP/1.1 on http-0.0.0.0-8080
[2012-11-28 12:33:55,424] [main] [INFO ] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProtocol: Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-0.0.0.0-8009
[2012-11-28 12:33:55,463] [main] [INFO ] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService: Starting service jboss.web
[2012-11-28 12:33:55,465] [main] [INFO ] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine: Starting Servlet Engine: JBoss Web/2.1.3.GA
[2012-11-28 12:33:55,594] [main] [INFO ] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina: Server startup in 170 ms
[2012-11-28 12:34:01,723] [main] [INFO ] org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool: Job execution threads will use class loader of thread: main
[2012-11-28 12:34:01,765] [main] [INFO ] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler: Quartz Scheduler v.1.5.2 created.
[2012-11-28 12:34:01,773] [main] [INFO ] org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore: RAMJobStore initialized.
[2012-11-28 12:34:01,773] [main] [INFO ] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Quartz scheduler 'DefaultQuartzScheduler' initialized from default resource file in Quartz package: 'quartz.properties'
[2012-11-28 12:34:01,773] [main] [INFO ] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory: Quartz scheduler version: 1.5.2
[2012-11-28 12:34:01,773] [main] [INFO ] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler: Scheduler DefaultQuartzScheduler_$_NON_CLUSTERED started.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by deleting the data/hypersonic folder and re-start.  It has large .script file (JBoss persists JMS messages here), probably that is causing the issue.

Comment: I know that it is a very old issue, but... How did you get to the conclusion that the _hypersonic_ folder had to be removed ? I am asking because this suggestion was not a solution for my case, but if I understand the logic, maybe I could find the one for my case.